# android menu item don't appeirs on topbar

Tags: android, menu, fragment, toolbar

```
 Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull @NotNull Menu menu, @NonNull @NotNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/item"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:translationY="52dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.gestion_actif.ActifActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/activity_topbar"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp" />
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

i use fragment and not activity.. my problem is that the toolbar appeirs but the items of the menu i don't found them when i run.
there is a code that i should write to to do the sychronisation between the menu and the topbar?
and i can use directly the topbar with menu from a fragment?

Comment: Use `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in onCreate of Fragment to enable option menu. also return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater); from `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: thank you. it resolved my problem